# DQL query doesn't return what I want

Tags: mysql, sql, dql

I'm a bit new with SQL query and I encounter a problem on my project.
In fact, this is my DQL query :

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass())->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder->select('p')
    ->from($this->getClass(), 'p');
if (!$this->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin('p.criteres', 'crit')
        ->leftJoin('crit.details', 'd')
        ->leftJoin('d.organes', 'o')
        ->leftJoin('o.atelier', 'a')
        ->where('a.country in (' . $this->getUserCountriesFormated().
            ') OR a.country IS NULL OR a IS NULL OR crit IS NULL OR d IS NULL OR o IS NULL');
}
$queryBuilder->orderby('p.name', 'ASC');
```

protocole to critere : many to many
critere to detail : many to many
detail to organe : many to many 
organe to atelier : many to one

Actually, all entries ascends because they have a NULL detail on 4/5 details. But they're linked to an atelier with a country in it, so I don't want to see them. I tried condition like (...) OR (d IS NULL AND a.country IS NULL) without success.

Sorry if my question looks obvious and thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: No problem, It's added.